# FormData Interface Issue on IE11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-11, form-data

Hi i use the FormData WebApi to collect Formdata and send it via Ajax to my Ruby on Rails Backend. 
Everything works as expected but i get an issue in IE11.

**Issue:**
* if i edit the form and without name and checkd "male" radio-button, the request is broken
* even if i don't edit the form, i.e. send it empty.

**Markup Example:**

```
<form action="/">

  <label for="input-1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="input-1" value="">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" value="male"/>
    <span>Male</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" value="female"/>
    <span>Female</span>
  </label>

  <button name="button" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

***Request Data**

```
-----------------------------7e33b51410242
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="radio-1[sex]"

male
-----------------------------7e33b51410242
Content-Disposition: form-data; input-1="
-----------------------------7e33b51410242--
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as below:

```
<form action="/">

  <label for="input_1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="input_1" value="">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="male"/>
    <span>Male</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="female"/>
    <span>Female</span>
  </label>

  <button name="button" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Besides, if still not working, you could create a FormData object and send the values, code like this:

```
var data = new FormData();
//you could use JavaScript script to get the value from the input elements.
data.append("filesToDelete", "Value");
data.append("clientContactId", 
(clientContactId != undefined || clientContactId != null) ? clientContactId : ''));

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/FileAttachment/UploadFiles",
        /* ONLY IF YOU ARE UPLOADING A FILE
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, */
        dataType: "JSON"
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        }
    });
```

More information, please refer to the following articles:

[Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)